# Pandas - How to rename a specific column based on index position

Tags: pandas

I am trying to rename a set of few columns in Pandas DataFrame. However the problem I have is there are several columns with the same name and hence when I try to rename all columns with the name get renamed. However I only want specific columns (by index position) renamed.

Given below are the column names :

```
customer_name, customer_address, customer_profile, customer_address
```

I would like to rename the column "customer_address" that appears in index 1 to be renamed to "address"

When I try the below both the columns with label `customer_address` get renamed to `address`

```
df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]: "address"}, inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First idea is set numpy array by position:

```
df.columns.to_numpy()[1] = 'address'
#old pandas versions
#df.columns.values[1] = 'address'
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [customer_name, address, customer_profile, customer_address]
Index: []
```

Another idea is change numpy array created from columns names:

```
arr = df.columns.to_numpy()
arr[1] = 'address'
df.columns = arr
print (df)
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [customer_name, address, customer_profile, customer_address]
Index: []
```